# How can I change the focused boder color of Tabpane header in javafx

Tags: javafx

Now I have a problem about my project what controlled by Keyboard. I have a TabPane with several tab as shown in the picture.

[image]

When I set the focus in tabPane.

```
posWindowController.mainTabPane.requestFocus()
```

the focus transfer to the TabPane's header where it have a blue border.I want to change the color of the border.what should I do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaFx 8 (or above), the default theme is modena.css. It is a good practice to find what you want to override in this styling sheet. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) and do not hesitate to use the [CSS reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) to know the default styleClass for JavaFX node.

By the way you can change the color of the tab's border by this style :

```
.tab-pane:focused>.tab-header-area>.headers-region>.tab:selected .focus-indicator {
   -fx-border-color: COLOR_YOU_WANT;
}
```